# Verifying $G*H$ Has Trivial Center and Elements of Infinite Order

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, free-groups

**Hypothesis:** Let $G \ne H$ denote two non-trivial groups.

**Goal:** Show that $G * H$ has a trivial center (hence is non-abelian) and contains an element of infinite order.

Is my attempted proof below valid?

**Attempt:**

1. Let $g \in G$ and $h \in H$ s.t. $g$ and $h$ are not equal to the identity elements of $G$ and $H$, respectively.  We can choose $g$ and $h$ this way since $G$ and $H$ are stipulated to be non-trivial.
2. Then $e \ne ghg^{-1}h^{-1}  \in G*H$.
3. Indeed, if $[g,h]$ denotes $ghg^{-1}h^{-1}$, then

   $$
   e \ne [g,h]^i \ne [g,h]^j \ne e
   $$

   for all naturals $i \ne j$.
4. Since $[g,h] \in G*H$ and $[g,h]^i \ne e$ for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$, we have that $[g,h]$ has infinite order in $G*H$.
5. Yet this means that $g$ and $h$ do not commute with each other in $G*H$ (when $g$ and $h$ are viewed as distinct elements in $G*H$).
6. Repeating the argument above for arbitrary elements $x \ne y$ in $G*H$ yields that $[x,y] \ne e$ in $G*H$ either (for all non-trivial elements $x,y \in G*H$).
7. Then it follows that any two non-trivial elements $x \ne y$ in $G*H$ do not commute with each other (since $[x,y] \ne e$ iff $x$ and $y$ do not commute with each other -- a fact from group theory).
8. Then $G*H$ has trivial center.
9. Then $G*H$ is in particular non-abelian.
10. And from (4), we have that $G*H$ has elements of infinite order.  This completes the proof.

---

**EDIT:** Since (6) in the above proof is false, here is another attempt to show that the center of $G*H$ is trivial:

1. Let $x \in G*H$ s.t. $x$ is not equal to the empty word (i.e., $x \ne e$).
2. If it happens that $x \in G$ or $x \in H$ (i.e., $x = g_1$ or $x=h_1$ for some $g_1 \in G$ or $h_1 \in H$), then let $y$ be a non-trivial element in the opposing group.  For example, if $x \in G$, then let $e_H \ne y \in H$  so that we have  $[x,y] \ne e$ in $G*H$.  The analogous result holds in case $x \in H$.
3. Now if it happens that $x \notin G$ or $x \notin H$, then we have that $x$  can be expressed in terms of its fully reduced form

   $$
   x = g_1 h_1 \cdot \ldots \cdot g_n h_n
   $$

   provided that $g_1$ and $h_n$ may be the empty word.
4. Now if we let $y$ be the first non-empty word in the above expression (i.e., if we let $y = g_1$ or $h_1$ depending on whether $g_1$ is empty or not), then we will have that

   $$
   [x, y] \ne e
   $$

   in $G*H$.
5. Then we have shown that in either case there exists some element $y$ in $G*H$ for which $[x,y] \ne e$. From group theory, we know that this is equivalent to saying that $x$ and $y$ don't commute with each other. Yet $x$ was arbitrary in $G*H$, and hence we have shown that any arbitrary (non-trivial) element in $G*H$ has another element which it does not commute with.
6. Then the center of $G*H$ is trivial.

Comment: Why not just use $gh$ as your infinite order element rather than $[g,h]$? Also, point 6 is not correct. We could have $x=y^2$ for example.

Comment: Derek -- I edited the proof above to show that the center of $G*H$ is trivial (you're right -- (6) is false as stated).  Also point taken on using $gh$ to more elegantly show $G*H$ has an element of infinite order.  Is my edit above correct?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to offer a slightly different proof:

Suppose $x\in G*H$ non-trivial. Then removing all the empty words, we see that WLOG $x=\prod_{i=0}^\infty a^{n_i}b^{m_i}$ (the order of $a^{n_i}b^{n_i}$ could be reversed), where $m_i,n_i\in\mathbb{Z}$, and $a\in G, b\in H$. Then taking a non-trivial element $b'\in B$, we see that $$b'x=b'\prod_{n=0}^\infty a^{n_i}b^{m_i}\neq \Big[\prod_{n=0}^\infty a^{n_i}b^{m_i}\Big]b'=xb'$$ The above is true by rules of concatenation, so it cannot be that $x$ is in the center; the center must be trivial.